# compare one list item against the rest in R

Tags: r, loops

If you have a list of files, and you want to compare 1 against a set of the others, how do you do it?

```
my.test <- list[1]
my.reference.set <- list[-1]
```

This works of course, but I want to have this in a loop, with my.test varying each time (so that each file in the list is my.test for one iteration i.e. I have a list of 250 files, and I want to do this for every subset of 12 files within it.

```
> num <- (1:2)
> sdasd<- c("asds", "ksad", "nasd", "ksasd", "nadsd", "kasdih")
> splitlist<- split(sdasd, num)
> splitlist
$`1`
[1] "asds"  "nasd"  "nadsd"

$`2`
[1] "ksad"   "ksasd"  "kasdih"

> for (i in splitlist) {my.test <- splitlist[i] # "asds"
+ my.reference.set <- splitlist[-i] # "nasd" and "nadsd"
+ combined <- data.frame (my.test, my.reference.set)
+ combined}
Error in -i : invalid argument to unary operator
>
```

then i want next iteration to be,

```
my.test <- splitlist[i] #my.test to be "nasd"
my.reference.set <- splitlist[-i] # "asds" and "nadsd"
}
```

and finally for splitlist[1],

```
my.test <- splitlist[i] # "nadsd" 
my.reference.set <- splitlist[-i] # "asds" and "ksad"
}
```

Then the same for splitlist[2]

Comment: If you create reproducible examples, chances are someone will take a look. (If the example isn't reproducible I tend to move on.) Now, you clearly can't make a reproducible example of 250 files. But that doesn't matter, since your question is about a list of 250 items. But it could just as well be 5 items. So, write some code with a list of 5 items that illustrates your problem. Then I'll try to understand your issue.

Comment: I elaborated on what Im trying to do.

Comment: OK, now add sample data and expected results. The point is that a "correct" answer will produce your expected results.

Comment: I'm working with binary bam files, so I can't really add them. Basically, once I have my.test and my.reference.set defined, I compare them using a few functions for bioinformatic analysis.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But that isn't the nub of your problem. Try to generalise your problem to comparing `objects`, not `files`. Once you have a working algorithm for comparing sets of objects, it will be easy to modify it to compare files.

Comment: Ive edited my question a bit more, added what I think is a generalisation. What I basically want to do is to create variables with variable1 being list[1] and variable2 being list[-1], but within in a loop. It's the syntax I want to fix, as I want 1 to be i (the i in the loop).

Comment: You're on the right track. Now delete all the stuff about files, and make the last bit reproducible. Then post expected results.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're asking for. How do I make it reproducible? My expected results are my.test and my.reference.set as mutually exclusive elements of a list (where my.reference.set contains all the elements of listX apart from the one defined as my.test, varying per iteration).

Comment: reproducible in the sense that we can copy-paste it into an R session and get a working example.

Comment: Ok, I've generalised it as much as I can and tried to show what I mean. I really appreciate all this help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?  The key point here is to loop over the *indices* of the list, rather than the names, because `x[-n]` indexing only works when `n` is a natural number (with some obscure exceptions).  Also, I wasn't sure if you wanted the results as a data frame or a list -- the latter allows the components to be different lengths.

```
num <- 1:2
sdasd <- c("asds", "ksad", "nasd", "ksasd", "nadsd", "kasdih")
splitlist<- split(sdasd, num)
L <- vector("list",length(splitlist))
for (i in seq_along(splitlist)) {
    my.test <- splitlist[[i]] # "asds"
    my.reference.set <- splitlist[-i] # "nasd" and "nadsd"
    L[[i]] <- list(test=my.test, ref.set=my.reference.set)
}
```

**edit**: I'm still a little confused by your example above, but I *think* this is what you want:

```
refs <- lapply(splitlist,
     function(S) {
         lapply(seq_along(S),
            function(i) {
               list(test=S[i], ref.set=S[-i])
           })
     })
```

`refs` is a nested list; the top level has length 2 (the length of `splitlist`), each of the next levels has length 3 (the lengths of the elements of `splitslist`), and each of the bottom levels has length 2 (test and reference set).

Comment: This seems to define my.test as more than one string, namely "ksad", "ksasd" and "kasdih". I want it to be one at a time, as I show in my newly edited post.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!! I would never have managed to write that... Thanks so much Ben!

Comment: @pepsimax If this answer was helpful, then you should really consider accepting it, by clicking on the tickmark below the answer score. This gives reputation (the SO currency) to the person who answered your question, and you also get a 2 points increase in rep.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Did that. I hope one day I can answer a question to return the favour!

Comment: @pepsimax Well done. You should also start to vote for answers to your questions.